# Drawing a circle for CLLocationManger region

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

I have a requirement where I have to draw a Circle with a given radius. For example, say 200 meters for `CLLocationManager`.

```
CLLocationDistance radius = 100.0;
CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc]initCircularRegionWithCenter:center radius:radius identifier:@"Apple"];
```

How do I draw the circle Using `CGpoint`? I am not using any map.

Comment: By the way, did you ever solve your question about how to take a bunch of latitude and longitudes and figure out how to project those onto the screens cartesian coordinate system? I've answered the "how do I draw a circle" question, but assume you've already done the math to figure out how you'll project these lat/long pairs into `CGPoint` references on the current view...

Comment: By the way, you've said you don't want to use maps, but have you considered re-visiting that decision? It simplify the "let me show a bunch of coordinates on the screen question". Also, as the boat approaches the shore, if you use the map, you could visually represent the shoreline. It just makes a bunch of things much easier. And you could, with some slight of hand, make it look like your radar-like UI, but still enjoy all of the benefits of a map view. Just a thought.

Comment: Can You show me How to do it..

Comment: You need two things to render lat/long coordinates on the screen: you need to define the "span" of lat/long coordinates to be represented in the circle, and you need to define the `frame` of screen `CGPoint` coordinates that those lat/long coordinates will be shown. Refer to [my answer to your follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16589746/1271826).

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two approaches:

1. Add QuartzCore.framework to your project, create a `UIBezierPath`, then create `CAShapeLayer` specifying its path, and then add the `CAShapeLayer` as a sublayer of your current view's layer. For example, I could call this from my view controller:

   ```
   #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

   - (void)addCircle
   {
       UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
       [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.layer.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.view.layer.bounds.size.height / 2.0) radius:self.view.layer.bounds.size.width * 0.40 startAngle:0.0 endAngle:M_PI * 2.0 clockwise:YES];

       CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
       layer.path = [path CGPath];
       layer.strokeColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
       layer.fillColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
       layer.lineWidth = 3.0;

       [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
   }
   ```
2. Subclass `UIView` and override `drawRect` to draw the circle with Core Graphics.

   ```
   @implementation CircleView

   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
   {
       CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

       CGContextAddArc(context, self.bounds.size.width / 2.0, self.bounds.size.height / 2.0, self.bounds.size.width * 0.40, 0, M_PI * 2.0, YES);

       CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
       CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
       CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);

       CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
   }

   @end
   ```

Both are valid. If you're not used to subclassing `UIView`, the former technique is probably easier.

#### References

The [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can draw like this and change it according to you what you wanna.
And you need to import `QuartzCore.framework` for it

```
int radius = 100;
CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];

circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*radius, 2.0*radius) 
                                         cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
// Center the shape in self.view
circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame)-radius, 
                              CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)-radius);

// Configure the apperence of the circle
circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
circle.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
circle.lineWidth = 5;

// Add to parent layer
[self.view.layer addSublayer:circle];
```